# Override inline styling of dropdown toggle in react-bootstrap w/o CSS class

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

Working on a project which requires me to convert a Bootstrap 4 based static site to a dynamic React app.

I am having trouble converting a certain piece of Sidebar menu which uses dropdown menus to present a set of links:

```
const DropdownNav = ({ title, sublinks, toggleId, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Dropdown as={NavItemLi} {...rest}>
      <Dropdown.Toggle as={Nav.Link} id={toggleId}>
        <span className="icon-holder">
          <i className="ti-view-list-alt" />
        </span>
        <span className="title">{title}</span>
        <span className="arrow">
          <i className="ti-angle-right"></i>
        </span>
      </Dropdown.Toggle>
      <Dropdown.Menu as="ul">
        {sublinks.map((item) => {
          <li>
            <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
          </li>;
        })}
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};
```

p.s The `NavItemLi` is basically a `Nav.Item` rendered as `li`.

Once rendered, the `Dropdown.Toggle` element is injected with some inline CSS that I believe is basically opening it as a popover/overlay rather than sliding/revealing the links down, is there any using the available API to change this functionality or do I need to go to CSS for this?

The dropdown is **working as**:
https://media1.giphy.com/media/mDQHX7okrcAqwwthvn/giphy.gif

How I actually **want it to work as**:
https://media2.giphy.com/media/XgVcxBTTGcigksf7qY/giphy.gif

Comment: have you inspect the visible items, whether it's removed from DOM on toggle ?

Comment: Yeah, it adds some unrequired inline-styling:

```<ul x-placement="bottom-end" aria-labelledby="drpDwnTglDri" class="dropdown-menu show" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px auto auto 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate(0px, 57px);" data-popper-reference-hidden="false" data-popper-escaped="false" data-popper-placement="bottom-end">  </ul>```